# PyTorch Two Losses of Two Variables

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, autograd

This is a question about PyTorch autograd.grad and the backward function specifically.

I have two tensors `a`, `b` which are optimized over (i.e. require gradients).

I define `loss1, loss2 = f(a,b), g(a,b)`. Although these are two separate functions `f` and `g`, for computational efficiency reasons, I have to compute both of them together as `fg(a,b)` which returns a tuple `(loss1, loss2)`.

I need to use `opt_a` and `opt_b` (optimizers) to step `a` and `b` with the following gradients:

`a.grad` should equal d (`loss1`)/ d (`a`)

`b.grad` should equal d (`loss2`)/ d (`b`)

How can I achieve these gradients? I know I can run `autograd.grad(loss1, a)` and `autograd.grad(loss2, b)` to get the true gradients and set them to `*.grad` manually, but I want to use the backward method on the `loss1` and `loss2`.

I want to use the backward method because it is concise code when in my case, a and b are actually the lists of parameters of two neural networks (I don't want to be manually setting `param.grad = ... for param in model1.parameters()`).

Is there a clean way to do this with `.backward()`?

---

**My Attempt**

I have tried multiple ordered variants of the following (but none of them work because the gradients add for one variable at least):

```
loss1, loss2 = fg(...)

opt1.zero_grad()
loss1.backward(retain_graph=True)
opt1.step()

opt2.zero_grad()
loss2.backward()
opt2.step()
```

Different orders of this result in either an accumulation of gradients (d (`loss1+loss2`)/ d (`a`)) or they result in one optimizer stepping the value of a, and then I can't run `b.backward()` because of an in-place operation change.

Some testing code I used:
[image]

Comment: Did you check `a.grad` after both steps have been performed? If so, that isn't quite correct. `opt1.step()` updates the parameters based on `a.grad` at that point, but it doesn't wipe them out and further changes to them won't have any effect without calling `opt1.step()` again, so the final value in `a.grad` isn't representative of the updates that have been performed. Could you verify that `a.grad` is correct after `opt1.step()`, or even better, could you check that `a`  was updated correctly at the end?

Comment: @MichaelJungo a.grad would be correctly updated definitely if it is the first step call. The problem is that since opt_a.step() changes the value of a (not a.grad), the call loss2.backward() fails because it relied on a previous version of a (its values). This results in the in-place change of version error.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I can't really see a version with `.backward()` without detaching `a` at some point, but that does not seem to be an option, since that would require `f` and `g` to be independent. I must say that I'm a little puzzled as to why `a` is used as a learnable parameter with `b` being constant and vice-versa, yet they share most of the computations.

Comment: I'm running a special adversarial setup with two neural net models. So model1(input), model2(input) are both used to compute loss1 and loss2.



But anyway, it feels ugly :/, but I ended up just manually setting up gradients like this:




grad_o = torch.autograd.grad(loss_o, model_o.parameters(), retain_graph=True)


grad_d = torch.autograd.grad(loss_d, model_d.parameters())


for i, params in enumerate(model_o.parameters()):
        params.grad = grad_o[i]


for i, params in enumerate(model_d.parameters()):
        params.grad = grad_d[i]

Comment: Okay, it might be your best bet then. But I still believe that the simplified example you provided was not entirely realistic. The snippet in your last comment is what I would have imagined, for which a solution would be `loss1 = f(output1, output2.detach())` and `loss2 = g(output1.detach(), output2)`, where `f` and `g` are the specific loss calculations, which are probably insignificant in terms of computational overhead compared to the models. Especially since you can avoid having to back propagate through the whole graph twice, and do it only once per model (two subgraphs).